# Validate numbers and letter in String

Tags: string, integer, character, validation

I need to input a String that is basically a membership number.

It has to contain two letters in the beginning followed by four numbers.

*For example*, `AA1111` or `AB1234`.

How can I validate that the first two digits are letters and the last four digits are integers?

Comment: What type of user interface? What have you tried? Show us some code. It's trivial to do even with the very basic language features without regexp etc. Side note: a digit is a *digit* not a letter.

Comment: What's your programming language, framework, library etc.?

Comment: My bad. It's java and I'm using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

In c#:

```
public void validate()
{
    string input = textBox1.Text;
    var re = "^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$";
    if (Regex.IsMatch(input, re))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("true");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("false");
    }
}
```

In javaScripts:

```
function validate() 
{
    var input = document.getElementById("Text1").value;
    var re = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$/);
    if (re.test(input)) 
    {
        alert("true");
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("false");
    }        
}
```

---

If we split regular expression, it validates input string in start and end

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}-----------------------------------------[0-9]{4}$
```

First two character must be alphabets

```
^         =*from start*  
[a-zA-Z]  =*lower and upper case alpha*  
{2}       =*Exactly two character*
```

Last four characters must be digits

```
[0-9]     =*digits*  
{4}       =*exactly four charater*  
$         =*at end*
```